# How to reclaim disk space on a MongoDB Atlas replica set?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I migrated a replica set from mLab to MongoDB Atlas.

mLab offered an [automated process](https://docs.mlab.com/ops/#compacting) to reclaim disk space after dropping large amounts of documents from a collection. Compacting (or resyncing) basically happened with the click of a button with a rolling node replacement process that does not require downtime.

I didn't find such a process in the MongoDB Atlas UI.

In the [mongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/resync-replica-set-member/#replica-set-auto-resync-stale-member) the steps to "automatically sync a member" require deleting data manually from the shut-down secondary, and possibly other steps that seem quite delicate.

What is the easiest way to reclaim disk space on MongoDB Atlas for a replica set with 1 primary and 2 secondaries?

Comment: What is the MongoDB version(x,y,z)?

Comment: It is MongoDB v3.6